# How to enable TLS 1.2 using SOAPConnection in Java 7

Tags: java, java-7, tls1.2

I'm trying to enable TLS 1.2 in a SOAPConnection in Java 7 running on Jboss 7.1.
I have read that the property https.protocols works only whit HttpURLConnection:

`System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2")`;

I have found a lot of solutions that say to use SSLContext:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
context.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
SSLContext.setDefault(context);
```

I have placed the code before the creation of my SOAPConnectionFactory, but that doesn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapFactory.createConnection();

SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);
```

Did you have any solutions? Thank's a lot

EDIT: It works, if I declare the SSLContext in the Interceptor.

Comment: But did you try the `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2")` solution? It may be "only" for HttpsURLConnection, but that includes everything that *uses* HttpsURLConnection too.

Comment: Yes, I use it in my Interceptor, and I also put it before the SOAPConnectionFactory, but it doesn't work.

Comment: When you set the SSLContext, does it only do it for that call?  Or does it set that globally?